Pourquoi ajouter « d' » devant "aucun" dans "ne ... aucun" ?
Pourquoi chacun des "d'aucun(e)" ci-dessous contient-il d'? Je les aurais écrits sans le d'.
Je connais  d'aucuns, “ne … aucun” = “not … one [of a set]” (i.e. “none”) —  mais ma question diffère.

A la différence du juge, il ne dispose d'aucun pouvoir et ne peut vous contraindre à accepter une solution qui ne vous satisferait pas.

Saskatoon (Ville de) c. Smith-Roles Ltd., [1978] RCS 1121

Mais cette conclusion est fondée sur des calculs de la valeur résiduelle qui ont débuté par l’évaluation de la valeur du terrain et des bâtiments, une estimation que je ne trouve d’aucun secours pour les raisons susmentionnées.

Guerin c. La Reine [1984] 2 RCS 335

Le juge de première instance a pris en considération tous les éléments de preuve pertinents et son jugement n'est entaché d'aucune erreur de principe: le montant des dommages-intérêts qu'il a fixé doit donc être adopté.


Il serait contraire au texte précis cette disposition de considérer que Sa Majesté peut, à son gré, mettre fin à ce droit sans que la bande ne dispose d'aucun recours.


La Cour d'appel fédérale ne nous est d'aucun secours à cet égard puisqu'elle a dégagé Sa Majesté de toute responsabilité.


A mon sens, son jugement n'est entaché d'aucune erreur de principe.

23 août 2023 Cour d'appel de Nîmes RG n° 23/00891

En l'espèce, Monsieur [L] [O] ne disposait au moment de son interpellation, d'aucun justificatif en original de son identité ni d'aucun document de voyage et n'en a pas davantage communiqué depuis aux autorités administratives, de telle sorte qu'il est nécessaire d'obtenir un laissez-passer consulaire avant que de pouvoir procéder à son éloignement effectif.


N'ayant pas de titre de séjour régulier, il ne peut exercer d'activité professionnelle régulière en France et ne dispose d'aucun revenu, ni possibilité de financement pour assurer son retour dans son pays.


Dans tous ces exemples, aucun introduit le groupe complément d'objet, qui est notoirement indirect. P. ex. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/disposer_de ; VTC.

D'aucuns pensaient que la question avait trait à d'aucuns.

Vraiment? D'aucunes façons, pourtant!

@FrançoisJurain Certes, mais pour un non francophone la construction d'un verbe n'est pas notoire à priori.

@None Roh boh l'aut'là! Pour d'aucuns non-francophones, sinon c'est pas du jeu.

@FrançoisJurain Ce d'aucuns était moi ! C'est ce que j'ai pensé en commençant à lire la question: Pourquoi ajouter « d' » devant "aucun" [...]

Les phrases citées ne pourraient pas s'écrire sans ce d' (de), la présence de la préposition de est entrainée par les structures verbales employées et est indépendante de l'emploi de aucun.
Disposer de
Être entaché de
Être de (quelque) secours

Il dispose de pouvoir →  il dispose de quelque pouvoir → il ne dispose pas de pouvoir  → il ne dispose d'aucun pouvoir
son jugement est entaché d'erreurs → son jugement n'est pas entaché d'erreurs → son jugement n'est entaché d'aucune erreur
il nous est de quelque secours → il ne nous est pas de secours →  il ne nous est d'aucun secours

